# IMAPX - Downloading .GZ - GZip Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap, imapx

When Downloading .gz files using IMAPX 2.0.0.18 I cannot extract the files as it shows them as corrupt. This happens when the file is under Message Attachments, when the same file is under Message Embedded it works fine.

I am using IMAPX with C# and ASP .NET, I am using the library quite extensively and the only problem that I am having is with downloading .gz attachments

I noticed that the bytes downloaded are not the same as the size of the file in Outlook,

- Am I missing something?
- Do I need to use `base64` encoding, if yes can you show a sample?
- How to use IMAPX's `attachment.download` and `attachment.save`

Comment: Are they bigger or smaller than the ones downloaded by Outlook? If they are bigger, can you try opening them in a text editor to see if they are binary files or base64 encoded? if they are base64 encoded, then you will need to decode them, otherwise it sounds like a bug in ImapX.

Comment: They are smaller, that's why I am confused as to why the complete file is not being downloaded.

Comment: It's possible that ImapX isn't parsing the response correctly. You could try using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead. If that doesn't work, nothing will.

Comment: Ok I will try but just for info, I tried s22.imap and it has the same issue,the file is smaller as compared to the size shown in outlook and when I pass the file to 7-zip,it says that this is not a GZip file.

Comment: Most IMAP libraries for .NET read the response into a string and then search for `) UID ...` to figure out the end of the data which is 100% the wrong way to do it. MailKit follows the spec and reads bytes and counts the exact number of bytes that the IMAP server specifies the size is.

Comment: Have you had any luck? If not, let me know what problem you are facing with MailKit and I can help you.

Comment: Hi @jstedfast My project is in .NET 4.0 and using Visual Studio 2010. In order to install the latest MailKit from the NuGet Pacakge I need Nuget Package Manaher console 2.1.12 or higher but VS 2010 does not support this version. May be I can get MailKit.dll and reference it manually in my project?

Comment: MailKit 1.22.0 had .NET4.0 support, so you could try that version.

Comment: Hi @jstedfast I was able to download the .GZ files correctly using MailKit 1.22.0

Comment: @jstedfast I also found it much much faster than IMAPX, below I am posting an issue that is currently happening

Comment: How can I find the current size of the MailBox using MailKit?

Comment: @jstedfast I have two questions for you regarding MailKit. I am using MailKit with .NET Framework 4.0 Question 1: How can I support TLS 1.2 for IMAP in MailKit? Do I need to upgrade to the latest .NET Framework?

Comment: @jstedfast Question 2: how can I search for email older than 90 days provided that my server does not support Within?

Comment: In order to get TLSv1.2 support, you need to upgrade your .NET to a version that supports it (4.6 or 4.7 I think?) and then MailKit will automatically support it. To search for messages older than 90 days, just do `folder.Search (SearchQuery.DeliveredBefore (DateTime.Now.AddDays (-90)))`.